# In R, conditionally mutate a new column for all of an ID's rows

Tags: r, dplyr

**Background**

I've got this dataframe `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(ID =    c("a","a","a","b", "c","c","c","c"),
                 event = c("red","black","blue","white", "orange","red","gray","green"),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

It's got some people in it (`ID`) and a description of an `event`. I'd like to make a new variable `condition` that indicates 1 or 0 based on whether any of the cells for a given `ID` contain either "red" or "blue".

**The Problem**

I can get this work, but only for the matching row. What I'd like is that if **any** of a person's cells in `event` contain "red" or "blue", **all** their cells in `condition` should be marked `1`. In other words, I'd like this:

```
ID  event condition
 a    red         1
 a  black         1
 a   blue         1
 b  white         0
 c orange         1
 c    red         1
 c   gray         1
 c  green         1
```

**What I've tried**

So far, I've used this code to get this result:

```
df <- df %>%
mutate(condition = ifelse(df$event %in% c("red","blue"), 1, 0))

ID  event condition
 a    red         1
 a  black         0
 a   blue         1
 b  white         0
 c orange         0
 c    red         1
 c   gray         0
 c  green         0
```

In other words, the **rows** that match are marked `1`, but I'd like all rows for an ID with any matching row to be marked `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need `any` wrapped around the logical vector from `%in%`- in addition the arguments can be reversed (In the OPs code, it is return 1 where it matches the elements 'red' or 'blue', leaving the others 0.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(condition = +(any(c('red', 'blue') %in% event))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
  ID    event  condition
  <chr> <chr>      <int>
1 a     red            1
2 a     black          1
3 a     blue           1
4 b     white          0
5 c     orange         1
6 c     red            1
7 c     gray           1
8 c     green          1
```

Comment: Thanks. Will run it now. Curious: what is the plus sign `+` doing before the open parentheses?

Comment: @logjammin it is to coerce the logical to binary (or use `as.integer`) as `TRUE->1` and `FALSE->0` (there is no need for `ifelse`)

Comment: Okay this worked very well. Thanks again. I'll mark the answer correct when it lets me in 9min.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(condition = if_else(str_detect(event, paste(c("red", "blue"), collapse = "|")), 1, 0))
```

```
  ID    event  condition
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
1 a     red            1
2 a     black          0
3 a     blue           1
4 b     white          0
5 c     orange         0
6 c     red            1
7 c     gray           0
8 c     green          0
```